# How to pass normal parameters in URL in Symfony?

Tags: routes, symfony1, query-string, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to pass parameters via a normal querystring, as such:

```
/user/login?foo=bar&abc=123
```

Unfortunately, nowhere does any data in an instance of `sfRoute` seem to contain data for params `foo` or `abc`.  How do I fix this?

**Edit:** Here is the code I'm using as per Tom's request:

/apps/api/config/routing.yml:

```
login:
  url:   /user/login
  param: { module: user, action: login }
```

/apps/api/modules/user/actions/actions.class.php:

```
class userActions extends sfActions {
    public function executeLogin(sfWebRequest $request) {
        echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->getRoute(), true).'</pre>';
    }
}
```

That's it.  The output shows that `$this->getRoute()` contains no info about `foo` or `abc` when I pass them in my query string with the URL "/user/login?foo=bar&abc=123".

Comment: Matt... added one more update.

Answer (score 2):

When accessing the variables, use the $request object, not sfRoute:

```
$request->getParameter('foo')
```

Do make sure the function in the action that's receiving those request params declares it as an incoming variable:

```
public function executeSomeAction($request)  {  }
```

If you're looking for the equivalent of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` in Symfony, I haven't found it and would be interested myself.

**UPDATE:**

I think the method you're using would only print the route. I think what you'll need to do to achieve this is to access them through the $request object, as I mentioned earlier. For example:

```
$params_typed = $request->getParameterHolder();  // ... and grab them from here
```

... or use server query string or handle the incoming params individually.

Sorry I can't be of more help.

**SECOND UPDATE:**

Actually, just tested a little idea:

if you define the params in your routing.yml like this:

```
login:
  url:   /user/login
  param: { module: user, action: login, foo: something, abc: something }
```

You can access them via:

```
$full_path = sfContext::getInstance()->getRouting()->getCurrentInternalUri();
```

Comment: But I'm trying to use the parameters in sfDoctrineRoute, and it's not accepting my parameters when I use them in the query string.

Comment: Does your routing rule have them in routing.yml? url: /user/login/:foo/:abc ....?

Comment: No, I don't want them to be part of the directory structure, I want to be able to type into the URL bar: /user/login?foo=bar&abc=123

Comment: I see... then by leaving them out of the routing rule and just putting what you have should work, including for typing it in. The only other thing I can think of is that you're appending them to the path using some non-standard way. I remember running into a few cases. Could you paste an example of how you're appending them in your code?

Comment: Or maybe I should clarify: Typing them in the URL bar should work without any tweaks and should make the params available to the action you're requesting. Is there something else you're looking to do with the params instead?

Comment: I pasted a simple example of the code I'm trying in the question.  I ultimately would like to use `sfDoctrineRoute` (or a custom route) that will take the parameters via GET, POST, or any other method, and use them when calling `$this->getRoute()->getObject()`.  Unfortunately, all route classes don't seem to see any of the parameters unless they're defined in the `url` line of routing.yml.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [adjust this in factories.yml](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/05-Factories#chapter_05_sub_extra_parameters_as_query_string) i think:

```
routing:
  class: sfPatternRouting
  param:
    extra_parameters_as_query_string: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you want to use the "extra_parameters_as_query_string: true" parameter you have to delete the final star of your route:

```
default:
  url:   /:module/:action
```